# minic iOS 7 UIBarButton font for UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd and others

Tags: ios, uibuttonbaritem

I would like to generate a button or label with the same visual plus sign or icons as used in the UIButtonBar system items. Is there a way to determine what font and characters are being used to generate these items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking this into two answers:

- The system fonts: Helvetica Neue Ultralight is used by iOS 7, while iOS 6 uses Helvetica (or more specifically, the nearly-identical Helvetica Neue).
- If you are trying to make icons that look like iOS defaults, I have used  http://www.glyphish.com/ successfully.